# For Loop is not applying nth-child correctly

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation, sass

Using Sass, I am looping through items with the class `animateMe` and applying an animation delay using the index as a multiplier.

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .animateMe:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: .5s * $i;
  }
}
```

Using Angular, I am applying the `animateMe` class on a div only when conditions are met with `ngClass`.

```
<div id="neededfoodnames" *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'animateMe':lists[i-1]?.category != list.category && animate == true}">
.....
</div>
```

This should only apply the class if the item's category is different than the last item's category and animate is set to true, which it is.

```
animate: boolean = true;
```

This results in 4 divs that have the `animateMe` class.
However, the animation-delay is not being applied correctly as the first and second div have the correct delays of .5s and 1s, respectively, while the third div has an incorrect delay of 3s.

The third div is getting the class `animateMe:nth-child(6)` but it should be `animateMe:nth-child(3)`.

How can I correct this? I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xn6ix4).

Comment: All the CSS seems to be fine (as in the sass loop is creating all your classes correctly so :nth-child is working as expected). Do you referring to how `#neededfoodnames:nth-child(4)` has no content? Or you are trying to overwrite your css with ng-animate

Comment: also PS you have multiple instances of `#neededfoodnames` in there :)

Comment: @stwilz I have removed `#neededfoodnames`. The `animateMe` class should only be applied to 4 divs, and therefore `animateMe:nth-child(6)` should not exist, but it does.

Comment: `lists[i-1]?.category` i see a typo here. dot after the question mark in your ternary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `lists` array has objects that are not considered an `animateMe` element. Only a few elements have the `animateMe` class. See this screenshot:

[image]

This screenshot explains why the `nth-child` selector is not working as expected. I see two solutions for you.

### Solution 1

The best solution is to clean up these elements. Ideally you should have only `animateMe` elements in that specific section, like this:

```
<div class="animateMe">...</div>
<div class="animateMe">...</div>
<div class="animateMe">...</div>
<div class="animateMe">...</div>
```

You should find a way of displaying the same UI, but with less `div` elements (e.g., using more styling or simply moving elements under the `animateMe` divs). If this is not possible for some reason, then you may consider solution #2.

### Solution 2

An alternative (and not so clean) solution for you is to preprocess that array and store an `order` attribute that can be used by the loop. For example:

```
lists = [{}, {order:1}, {}, {}, {order:2}, {}, {order:3}, {}, {}];
```

You can then loop through the array and add a `data-order` attribute that we can match with CSS:

```
<div *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'animateMe': list.order && animate}" [attr.data-order]="animate ? list.order : null">
    ...
</div>
```

If the `order` property is not defined in your object, the `data-order` attribute won't be printed. Here is an example of output:

```
<div>...</div>
<div class="animateMe" data-order="1">...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div class="animateMe" data-order="2">...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div class="animateMe" data-order="3">...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
```

The last step is to change your SaSS code to match those elements:

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    div[data-order="#{$i}"].animateMe {
        animation-delay: .5s * $i;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's bad practice to target elements in CSS by their element tag type, you can remove `div` from the above Sass and it will still work as expected.

Comment: @EdmundReed Can you please post a link to a reference that confirms that this is bad practice? Considering that browsers usually index elements by nodeName, the `div` should make the selector more efficient and that, by definition, is a good practice.

Comment: Perhaps it's microscopically better for performance, but for maintainability and scalability it's bad practice. This article looks like it explains why https://frontstuff.io/you-need-to-stop-targeting-tags-in-css. With things like this, maintainability and scalablity tend to be favored over minuscule performance gains.